# Using Collections in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

The following would be the model of a simple backbone application. So consider i want to have more than one url calls, i am told i should be using collections(definition is a collection of models).

Model format :

```
    var Books1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/books1'
    });

    var Books2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/books2'
    });
```

Collection format :

```
    var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/books'
    });
```

My question is how can i like **combine more than one model in a collection ?**

To be more clear :

Consider i have currently 8-10 models in a single view(need to call 8+ server requests from a single view). I am succesfully doing this via models. But from my initial research i came to conclusion that i should be using collection which will be a collection of all the models used. So by passing the collection to view, i will be able to call out different models at different part of view as requried.

**And how do i use it in a view?**

To be more clear :

for a model now i use `this.model.save()` or `newmodel.save()` after declaring the model before the place where i need to have the request done.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

lots of properties is handled via http://underscorejs.org/#result so you can pass urlRoot as function

```
var Books = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: function(){
    return condition ? '/books' : '/bum'
  } 
});
```

same in collection. But I don't think so, its a good idea to combine 2 or more models in one collection. Just make a new collection for another model, if its possible....

what about view?

you can pass collection to view instance like this:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(opt){
    this.collection = new opt.collection
  }
});

var someView = new SomeView({collection: Books})
```